# iOS: dismiss popOver generated with Interface Builder with button within the popOver

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have a button which leads to a popOver, all created in Interface Builder. The popOver is closed when I press somewhere outside of it, but I would also like to implement a button within the popOver which does that.

I found a solution by Giorgio Barchiesi dating back to 2011, however I fail to implement it. Here's his solution:

In the implementation file of the source view controller:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[MyDestViewController class]]) {
        MyDestViewController* viewController = (MyDestViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue* popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;
        [viewController setPopoverController:[popoverSegue popoverController]];
    }
}
```

In the header file of the destination view controller:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIPopoverController* popoverController;
```

In the implementation file of the destination view controller:

```
@synthesize popoverController;
```

Same file, whenever you want to dismiss the popover:

```
[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

i could call the last function when the button is pressed.
My problem is that XCode gives me an error on the `[viewController setPopoverController:[popoverSegue popoverController]]` line: *ARC Semantic Issue: No known class method for selector 'setPopOverController'*

What did I miss to implement?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the method I use:

Open your storyboard file, select the segue arrow and open the Attributes Inspector (Option - Command - 4) and identifier fill in a sensible name, like "myPopoverSegue".

In your Source View Controller define a variable right after @implementation :

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    __weak UIPopoverController *myPopover;
}
```

Then, again in the Source VC:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:[dict objectForKey:@"myPopoverSegue"]]) {//@"segue" is your segue name. You can use isKindOfClass as you do currently, I prefer this method.
        myPopover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
    }
}

-(void)closePopover{
    [myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

In the end of your Source VC's viewDidLoad method write:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closePopover) name:@"popoverShouldDismiss" object:nil];
```

Finally, whenever you want to dismiss the popover:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popoverShouldDismiss" object:nil];
```

Hope this helps!
This way you will also be able to change the segue to a different controller without changing your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the delegate < UIPopoverControllerDelegate > to your class and override the delegate method:

```
 - (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
 {
     return NO;
 }
```

This will prevent the popover to be dismissed when user presses anywhere on screen.
Now you can dismiss your popover inside the button's selector method by using:

```
  [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: thank you, but i didn't ask how to stop dismissing the popOver when the user pushes outside of it. instead i asked how to dismiss it from a button within the popOver?

Comment: Are you calling method like:  [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; in the button's selector method such as -(IBAction) buttonPressed{  [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; } Is this not working?

Comment: Yes I'm. The problem is that the popoverController can't dismiss just itself. It needs a reference from it's root view and that's was user chandan tried to solve, but I must have forgotten something since it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 it's really easy. Just call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Pop overs are regular presentation controllers, so it's more or less the exact same thing as a modal view controller.

Comment: It is definitely the right way. I create an `IBAction` linked to the button in this way: `- (IBAction)pressedCloseButton:(id)sender { [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[MyDestViewController class]]) 
    {
        MyDestViewController* viewController = (MyDestViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];

        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue* popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;

        popoverSegue.popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];

        [popoverSegue.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(viewController.view.frame.size.width, viewController.view.frame.size.height)];

        popoverSegue.popoverController.delegate=self;

        [viewController setPopoverController:popoverSegue.popoverController];
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but it doesn't work in my case.
when i try to set the `popoverSegue.popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];` method i can't set my root ViewController there _(Unexpected interface name 'ViewController')_ and i it still returns the same error on the setPopOverController function. Do I have to somewhere set a property for my ViewControllers in the .h file?